# Select query run in `Visual Studio` but not in browser

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, select, visual-studio-2013

I have a datalist control which is connected to a SQLDataSource when i test the data source query with the query builder it returns the data set however when i then run the website in any browser the query does not return a data set.

`It seems like the website is not recompiling properly however i am not getting any build errors.`

Does anyone have any idea for a possible solution.

Thanks in advance

my sqldatasource code is-

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceSearch" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BazaarCeramicsConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Categories.Name, Products.ProductID, Products.Name AS Expr1 FROM Products INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID WHERE (Products.Name LIKE '%' + @SearchQuery + '%')">
        <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="SearchQuery" QueryStringField="search" 
            Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

my datalist code is-

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSearch">
        <ItemTemplate>
            Name:
            <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
            <br />
            ProductID:
            <asp:Label ID="ProductIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
            <br />
            Expr1:
            <asp:Label ID="Expr1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Expr1") %>' />
            <br />
```

Here is my input-

```
<div class="searchBox">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="SearchTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Search" />
                    <a href="ShoppingCart.aspx"><img id="cartIcon" src="Images/shoppingCartIcon.png" /></a>
               </div>
```

Here is the code behind

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SearchTerm = SearchTextBox.Text;
    Response.Redirect("SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=" + Server.UrlEncode(SearchTerm));
}
```

here is my connection string-

```
<add name="BazaarCeramicsConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=CATHERINE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BazaarCeramics;User ID=****;Password=******"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code for the `SQLDatasource` and where you want to display it.

Comment: Can you show the code and what value you are setting for the `SearchQuery` parameter

Comment: You are using a QueryStringParameter, in your URL, are you seeing search=1 or another variable? It should look something like www.test.com/Testing/page.aspx?search=1... if there is no search parameter or it's blank, it will not return a result.

Comment: Hi Bhavesh i have added the search box, button and code behind i am using

Comment: Hi Humpy yes the query is appending to the URL as shown I know that this is an item that appear multiple times in my database and that this same seach returns result in the query builder. http://localhost/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=Bambi

Comment: What is your connection string? If you're using integrated authentication or a Trusted connection, this can happen because the visual studio web browser will use your account when connecting to the DB, but the web site will use the asp.net account, which likely does not have any access to the DB.

Comment: Hi Joel i have added my connection string to the question i created the connection using the data source configuration wizard. I am sorry i do not know if i am using integrated authentication or a trusted connection but i will do more research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Products.Name LIKE '%' + @SearchQuery + '%')
```